# Struggling to convert javascript script to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert a javascript snippet to typescript, the javascript version looks to be working but I'm struggling a bit with to refactor the promise part in typescript.

javascript code

```js
var youtubeCaptionsScraper = require("youtube-captions-scraper")

function srtTimestamp(seconds) {
    var $milliseconds = seconds*1000;
    
    $seconds = Math.floor($milliseconds / 1000);
    $minutes = Math.floor($seconds / 60);
    $hours = Math.floor($minutes / 60);
    $milliseconds = $milliseconds % 1000;
    $seconds = $seconds % 60;
    $minutes = $minutes % 60;
    return ($hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + $hours + ':'
         + ($minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + $minutes + ':'
         + ($seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + $seconds + ','
         + ($milliseconds < 100 ? '0' : '') + ($milliseconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + $milliseconds;
}

function inputToSRT(srtCount, sub_in) {
  return srtCount + "\r\n" + srtTimestamp(sub_in.start) + " --> " + srtTimestamp(sub_in.dur) + "\r\n" + sub_in.text + "\r\n\r\n";
}
  
async function getUrlSrtSubtitles(url, language) {

   await youtubeCaptionsScraper.getSubtitles({
      videoID: url.split("v=")[1].split("&")[0], // youtube video id
      lang: language
    }).then(captions => {
        console.log(captions);
        // formating captions to srt text format
        srtCount = 0;
        srtString = '';
        for (var i=0; i<captions.length; i++) {
          srtString = srtString + inputToSRT(++srtCount, captions[i]);
        }

        console.log(srtString);
        return srtString;
    });


}

var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wnfj-b-wp4";
getUrlSrtSubtitles(url, 'en')
```

I've validated my first part [here](https://npm.runkit.com/youtube-captions-scraper)

I'm not sure how to refactor the promise from js getUrlSrtSubtitles function into typescript so it works, any help would be appreciated.

thanks

The typescript code I've made so far looks like this

src/types.ts

```js
export interface SubCaptions {
  start: string;
  dur: string;
  text: string;
}
```

src/utils.ts

```js
const youtubeCaptionsScraper = require("youtube-captions-scraper"); // youtubeCaptionsScraper
import {SubCaptions} from "./types";


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// youtubeCaptionsScraper functions
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////


export function srtTimestamp(seconds: number): string {
    
    var milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
    seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    milliseconds = milliseconds % 1000;
    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    return (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours + ':'
         + (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':'
         + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds + ','
         + (milliseconds < 100 ? '0' : '') + (milliseconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + milliseconds;
}


export function inputToSRT(srtCount: number, sub_in: SubCaptions) {
  return srtCount + "\r\n" + srtTimestamp(Number(sub_in.start)) + " --> " + srtTimestamp(Number(sub_in.dur)) + "\r\n" + sub_in.text + "\r\n\r\n";
}

export function getUrlCaptions(url: string, language:  string): Array<SubCaptions> {
  
  const captionsArray = youtubeCaptionsScraper.getSubtitles(
    {
      videoID: url.split("v=")[1].split("&")[0], // extract youtube video id
      lang: language
    }
  )

  return captionsArray 
}


export function getUrlSrtSubtitles(url: string, language:  string): string {

  const captionsArray = getUrlCaptions(url, language);

  // declare var
  var srtCount = 0;
  var srtString = '';

  // formating captions to srt text format
  for (var i=0; i<captionsArray.length; i++) {
    srtString = srtString + inputToSRT(++srtCount, captionsArray[i]);
  }

  console.log(srtString);

  return srtString;

}
```

Any help dealing with this promise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`youtubeCaptionsScaper.getSubtitle` returns a Promise, so you can't declare `getUrlCaptions` to return a simple `SubCaptions[]`, you can do the following:

```
export async function getUrlCaptions(
  url: string,
  language: string
): Promise<SubCaptions[]> {
  return youtubeCaptionsScraper.getSubtitles({
    videoID: url.split("v=")[1].split("&")[0], // extract youtube video id
    lang: language,
  });
}
```

And in order to use this make sure to use `await`

```
const captions = await getUrlCaptions(url, language);
```

You can check it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBATwgVxsgRgUwMIEMwzAQB2AzgMoDGU+mUcAZlBCHAERKoaYC0l+hEqR6lqtKGwDcAKGkNkxSoOJxSsACqhMpGLnAAKUpkokAJqQBccYshBYoASjgBvaXDgAbTPAAkIYB4ewEYmxOZwALyqxmakcABUcACMAAxpMm6e3nA+IbGRcACyuDAAFgB0DB4Q0Pp+AUF5YXEA9MlpKQ4y7l6+-jYw2gXFZZXVtbkxzXBtAGyd3Vm+pShQcVEjFVU1UHX9qENzC5n1gcFT4VGnjRdxAKTt6SdNlzkv93Dzi-UDQ1f7gw+X0yUG8yCgKn0mXcdRW4LiAB52nAAPzsFJsOBWNhsJwAamhOThazgBPc7jYFkxZPJe2Av0RyLRbAxWPYuNJhJ+BziNIpVM55LgdXecCRqVR6Mx2I5fLet0F5LYABpqYS6WdReK0pKWdL2fj1ddzqFwtrdayZYahcb3pkutIAL6yGAIMCYODkDB4AhEMgFVzuHS4WBWGx2OiLUzgsO2eyLQYADxgVh0UHpAHMZM65AolH64PSwKh1BByAAldSGWDYFDEFPWON0ZWqDAAfXpVi96B9ylITkDcFBaAhcAABj5nGoYLWFDBHQAdKAL4iT6eaEDaXQGUjt+nlYOwByOuA8M8APhyU40WmDBkJu-QHeI5WjUHti+Xq6ne5fSfnS4roBxBjtmsi4KQCCKIwebKHAGbeAAqlAHi9n6pBQu44IeKmMDpsQGbKpkHi4ARyC4AhuH4Rm0gOFYAAKzD+EYCLdmhQgANoALqXoOw7gionBoFg7FkFQNDulA5QITA3aEDAXgYYO7gAG7AKYmAQAAkgAIlY2EHmAQQwPobAqREuIcUkXGGcZpkAGSWSkXEti0bSYMmNBKIgKDCR6akaRAhamISJEEVYYUZuRCFEe4joOjmEFQZQMGKHBMnIR45CwHJwAKdo+jYVRmYtpF0WYMVBEDpkoQ6HA-C+kIBS4AA7rgeXwUhKGiRh2GlaRUUUZgDruLVEBeOU1QZvoDV9iNMxtAw0AgCUmb1QI6FwDAQXTltHnwEtUArTAxHZNOs71gUKSLL0qg5Xha1RDiiyHcKt3AFdkiFmK62NWQk2YARZRfcAeJ4tVQrTuQD0EQUUMwxmpKFsQxYwKWFZVmD511jALazehHHAFx805qNQjjZgk0QNN8PUfN-GjrTmZgdIt3YQUbClDAMBgJYbktQL5RCdw5QmCALRtTAlClCi5kAOwtcQDAAFY8OgPAtWAAAsUjSK17XwBlKHZbJGDyYphUoS2bCA7iMhAA)